# mapping / write assist with csvhelper

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, mapping, csvhelper

Quick help here please on csvhelper...

csv:
Name,LastName

PersonMap:

```
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name).Name("Name");
        Map(x => x.LasName).Name("LastName");
    }
```

Person Class:

```
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Main:

```
 public void writePerson()
 {
        IEnumerable<Person> records;
        using (var r = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("person.csv")))
        {
            r.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonMap>();
            records = r.GetRecords<Person>().ToList();     
        } 

        using (var w = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("person.csv")))
        {
            w.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonMap>();
            w.WriteRecord(records); //rewrite csv list
            w.WriteField("John")); 
            w.WriteField("Doe");
            w.NextRecord();             
        }
    }
```

ERROR LINE:   records = reader.GetRecords().ToList();

ERROR: 
No header record was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so I fixed it with the following:

Write:

```
string persondata = "John, Doe";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.csv", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        { sw.WriteLine(persondata); sw.Dispose(); }
```

Read:

```
IEnumerable<Person> records;
using (var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"person.csv")))
{
        reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonMap>();
        records = reader.GetRecords<Person>();
}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Can you explain what the fix was?  Removing "ToList()" from the call to GetRecords<T>()?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your person.csv doesn't have the first line as a header line as follows:

```
Name,LastName
```

Please check the CSV file.

Comment: can you please paste first 2-3 line of csv file with header and the exception stack trace you get?

Answer (score 0):

Add following configuration line

`w.configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;`